# How to implement Magento Captcha in Contact- Us form?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, contact-us, captcha

I need to show default magento captcha in contact-us page.

Comment: Check link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33743012,this will help you.

Comment: I mistakenly added the solution for magento 2 .

Comment: I complete all the steps but it doesn´t work by me - Magentoshop 1.9

Comment: Please dont add your question as answers

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/144225)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Created a new module for this.

**Step 1**:

> app/code/local/Contact/Captcha/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Contact_Captcha>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Contact_Captcha>
</modules>
<default>
    <captcha>
        <frontend>
            <areas>
                <contact_page_captcha>
                    <label>Contact Page</label>
                </contact_page_captcha>
            </areas>
        </frontend>
    </captcha>
</default>
 <global>
    <models>
        <contact_captcha>
            <class>Contact_Captcha_Model</class>
        </contact_captcha>
    </models>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_contacts_index_post>
            <observers>
                <captcha>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>contact_captcha/observer</class>
                    <method>checkContactPage</method>
                </captcha>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_contacts_index_post>
    </events>
</global>
</config>
```

**Step 2:**

> app/etc/modules/Contact_Captcha.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Contact_Captcha>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Contact_Captcha>
</modules>
</config>
```

**Step 3:**

> app/code/local/Contact/Captcha/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Contact_Captcha_Model_Observer extends Mage_Captcha_Model_Observer
{
public function checkContactPage($observer)
{
    $formId = 'contact_page_captcha';
    $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
    if ($captchaModel->isRequired()) {
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($this->_getCaptchaString($controller->getRequest(), $formId))) {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
            $controller->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('*/*/'));
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
}
```

**Step 4:**

> Create a local.xml in theme path.
>
> app/design/frontend/theme/default/layout/local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
 <contacts_index_index translate="label">
    <reference name="contactForm">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
            <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                <reference name="head">
                    <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                </reference>
                <action method="setFormId"><formId>contact_page_captcha</formId></action>
                <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</contacts_index_index>
</layout>
```

**Step 5:**

> app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/contacts/form.phtml

Add below code:

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
```

**Step 6:**

> Admin Settings:

```
Dashboard - > Customers - > Customer Configuration - > CAPTCHA - > Forms - > Select Contact Page
```

**Step 7:**

Clear cache. Refresh contact us page.

Comment: Your answer is better than mine.

Comment: For what it's worth, in my Magento 1.9, I had to add the following code in  app/code/local/Contact/Captcha/etc/config.xml within the tag <default>:

        <customer>
            <captcha>
                <always_for>
                    <contact_page_captcha>1</contact_page_captcha>
                </always_for>
            </captcha>
        </customer>

Comment: How can I apply the same code for a CMS Page? I'm loading the Contact form inside a CMS Page. I have: www.domain.com/contact , and here I load the contact form using: {{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}} . Thanks.

Comment: For me it didn't work at first: `Warning: include(): Failed opening '/includes/src/Contact_Captcha_Model_Observer.php'`
I had to manually copy the Observer.php file over to the includes/src directory for it to work. Any idea why?

Comment: Its not working on 1.9.2.2.

Comment: @Víctor because your shop ist compiled, you should disable / re-enable this when installing a module

Comment: The captcha form is not showing for me

Answer (score 4):

You need to either create a custom module or install an extension for this.

Below is the code for implementation as a custom module:

> app/etc/modules/Mohit_Contactcaptcha.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mohit_Contactcaptcha>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mohit_Contactcaptcha>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Mohit/Contactcaptcha/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mohit_Contactcaptcha>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mohit_Contactcaptcha>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <contactcaptcha>
                    <file>contactcaptcha.xml</file>
                </contactcaptcha>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <contactcaptcha>
                <class>Mohit_Contactcaptcha_Model</class>
            </contactcaptcha>
        </models>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_contacts_index_post>
                <observers>
                    <contactcaptcha>
                        <class>contactcaptcha/observer</class>
                        <method>checkContacts</method>
                    </contactcaptcha>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_contacts_index_post>
        </events>
    </global>
    <default>
        <captcha>
            <frontend>
                <areas>
                    <contacts>
                        <label>Contacts Page</label>
                    </contacts>
                </areas>
            </frontend>
        </captcha>
        <customer>
            <captcha>
                <always_for>
                    <contacts>1</contacts>
                </always_for>
            </captcha>
        </customer>
    </default>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Mohit/Contactcaptcha/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Mohit_Contactcaptcha_Model_Observer
{
    public function checkContacts($observer){
        $formId = 'contacts';
        $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
        if ($captchaModel->isRequired()){
            $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
            $word = $this->_getCaptchaString($controller->getRequest(), $formId);
            if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($word)) {
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
                $controller->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
                $url =  Mage::getUrl('contacts');
                $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
    /**
    * Get Captcha String
    *
    * @param Varien_Object $request
    * @param string $formId
    * @return string
    */
    protected function _getCaptchaString($request, $formId)
    {
        $captchaParams = $request->getPost(Mage_Captcha_Helper_Data::INPUT_NAME_FIELD_VALUE);
        return $captchaParams[$formId];
    }
}
```

> app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/contactcaptcha.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <contacts_index_index>
        <reference name="contactForm">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>contactcaptcha/contacts/form.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
                <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                    <reference name="head">
                        <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                    </reference>
                    <action method="setFormId"><formId>contacts</formId></action>
                    <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                    <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </contacts_index_index>
</layout>
```

> app/design/frontend/default/default/template/contactcaptcha/contacts/form.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Us') ?></h1>
</div>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Information') ?></h2>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="telephone"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="wide">
                <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="required"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

After creating the module, login to admin panel and navigate to **Store > Configuration > Customers > Customers Configuration > Captcha**
and select **Contacts Page** from given options

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: Thnks for the reply. .I have already find the solution and posted the answer.

Comment: Great to know that you have found the solution. Also thanks for sharing your findings.

Comment: How can I apply the same code for a CMS Page? I'm loading the Contact form inside a CMS Page. I have: www.domain.com/contact , and here I load the contact form using: {{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}} . Thanks.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora, This is not showing the captcha in front-end page of contact us page

Comment: @jafarpinjar, are you working in Magento 1.9.x?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora, Yes there is live site which was done in magento 1.9.3.2, Need to implement this feature

Comment: @MohitKumarArora,could you update me working code pls..

Comment: @jafarpinjar, I have shared the module to your email. Please check. You may need to copy and paste layout and template files from default theme to your working theme.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora, Yes let me try your code, thanks

Comment: @MohitKumarArora, Thank you, Its working great!!

Comment: @MohitKumarArora, One small issue with captcha, actually we have contact form in footer also, there its not showing any captcha, where as its working well in contact page, can we show captcha in footer where we are using the contact form

Answer (score -1):

how to fix Contact-us page captcha not showing in magento 1?

Comment: Did you try the options mentioned above? What's the issue you are getting?