# Contact-us page captcha not showing on another page using the same template

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, forms, contact-us, captcha

I added a captcha on the contact-us page following the guide here: [How to implement Magento Captcha in Contact- Us form?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196752/how-to-implement-magento-captcha-in-contact-us-form)

it seems to be working perfectly, the problem is that I have another CMS-page that calls the same contact-us form template like this:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

the problem is that the captcha is not working on that page, yet it keeps working on the default contact-us page, even if the form should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, every element on the page is shown on the basis of layout handle, by which it has been called.

For example: if captcha has been called on the action **`/contacts`**, then the layout handle **`contacts_index_index`** will be able to show captcha.

To call captcha for contact form in the cms page, you would need to write layout update for the cms page.

**Update:** You need to go to the cms page, click on the Design tab and enter the layout update XML in the Custom Layout Update XML textarea.

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="contactForm">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>contactcaptcha/contacts/form.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="setFormAction">
            <form_action>contacts/index/post</form_action>
        </action>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
            <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                <reference name="head">
                    <action method="addJs">
                        <file>mage/captcha.js</file>
                    </action>
                </reference>
                <action method="setFormId">
                    <formId>contacts</formId>
                </action>
                <action method="setImgWidth">
                    <width>230</width>
                </action>
                <action method="setImgHeight">
                    <width>50</width>
                </action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Next, click on **Content** tab and put **`&nbsp;`** in the textarea.

Then click on Save Page button and flush Magento Cache.

**Note:** Even though the form will start showing captcha on the page, but after submitting the form, it will redirect to the default contacts page.

**Note:** Every time when you will open the cms page, you need to put **`&nbsp;`** in the textarea before saving the page.

Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: It already works on the /contacts page, as I already have a "contacts_index_index" handle, I want it to work on a page which page key is "company", tried writing a handle called "company_index_index", but doesn't seem to work

Comment: Since "company" is a cms page, the layout handle **`company_index_index`** will not work.

Comment: @Arnold.M, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: @Arnold.M, please check my updated answer.

Comment: Neither with the &nbsp; the captcha is still not working. If it might be of any help I heve more html in the "content" text area.

Comment: If you have more content to show from the content tab text area, then there is no need to add &nbsp;

Comment: BTW what error or issue you are getting?

Comment: That the captcha is not showing by any means, the form works and everything, but when I submit it says "Wrong captcha" because there isn't any captcha input.

Comment: The answer I posted is for native Magento 2 captcha.

Comment: I'm using native Magento captcha! And if you look at the question tags I'm not using magento2 but instead 1.9.

Comment: @Arnold.M, sorry I posted similar answer for 2 different questions. and I mistakenly posted comment for Magento 2 here ;)