# How can I add captcha to newsletter form?

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, newsletter, captcha

I've added captcha to contact us form by following [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/196759/49826)

I'm wondering while its not working with newsletter form ?

here's what I tried.

```
<cms_index_index translate="label">
        <reference name="newsletter-validate-detail">
               <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
                <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                    <reference name="head">
                        <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                    </reference>
                    <action method="setFormId"><formId>newsletter_captcha</formId></action>
                    <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                    <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
                </block>
            </block> 
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
```

> config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Contact_Captcha>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Contact_Captcha>
</modules>
<default>
    <captcha>
        <frontend>
            <areas>
                <contact_page_captcha>
                    <label>Contact Page</label>
                </contact_page_captcha>
                <newsletter_captcha>
                    <label>Newsletter Form</label>
                </newsletter_captcha>
            </areas>
        </frontend>
    </captcha>
</default>
 <global>
    <models>
        <contact_captcha>
            <class>Contact_Captcha_Model</class>
        </contact_captcha>
    </models>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_contacts_index_post>
            <observers>
                <captcha>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>contact_captcha/observer</class>
                    <method>checkContactPage</method>
                </captcha>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_contacts_index_post>
        <controller_action_predispatch_newsletter_subscriber_new>
            <observers>
                <captchanews>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>contact_captcha/newsletterObserver</class>
                    <method>checkNewsletterPage</method>
                </captchanews>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_newsletter_subscriber_new>
    </events>
</global>
</config>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you showing the newsletter form in contact us page alone or in all pages under footer?

Comment: Yes In footer newsletter at all pages. not included in to contact form.

Comment: check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133238/magento-2-how-to-add-captcha-to-a-custom-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code in your layout file. 
Changed `<reference name="newsletter-validate-detail">` to  `<reference name="footer.newsletter">`

```
<cms_index_index translate="label">
            <reference name="footer.newsletter">
                   <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
                    <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                        <reference name="head">
                            <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                        </reference>
                        <action method="setFormId"><formId>newsletter_captcha</formId></action>
                        <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                        <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
                    </block>
                </block> 
            </reference>
        </cms_index_index>
```

Comment: Let me try with your solution.

Comment: Does the above solution works?

Comment: This works on the home page only because of you added cms_index_index layout.

Comment: Yes, Because of @Vivek has added `cms_index_index` in his layout.

Comment: If you want to show on all page then remove `cms_index_index` from layout and put rest of the code under `<default></default>` tag.

Comment: I have add a link to newsletter for text. When i click it will go to newsletter page and form will be shown i have used above code removing <cms_index_index> but captcha is not showing in that form..

Comment: Please add here what you have tried. So I can suggest you further.

Comment: i have form in CMS Block, i want to add captcha for that form, please suggest me.